# How to find reduction formula for $I_n=\int\frac{1}{x^n \sqrt{x^2-1}}dx$

Tags: integration, reduction-formula

I have tried manipulating the integral but couldn't come up with an answer that matched textbook answer.
I just need a hint. Thanks in advance.
$\int\frac{dx}{x^n \sqrt{x^2-1}}$

This is what I tried:
Let $I_{n-2}=\int\frac{dx}{x^{n-2} \sqrt{x^2-1}}$
Then I integrated by parts.

The answer given in textbook is

$$(n-1)I=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^{n-1}} +(n-2)I_{n-2}$$

Comment: (1) Show what you tried. (2) What is the textbook answer?

Comment: Try substituting $x=\sec \theta$.

Comment: The substitution makes the integral  $$\int cos^{n-1}(θ)dθ$$ if I am right and the absolute value is ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce the integral as follows

\begin{align}
I_n= &\int\frac{1}{x^n \sqrt{x^2-1}}dx \\
=& \int\frac{(1-x^2)+x^2}{x^n \sqrt{x^2-1}}dx
=-\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^n }dx + I_{n-2} \\
=&\ \frac1{n-1}\int \sqrt{x^2-1} \>d\left(\frac{1}{x^{n-1} }\right)+ I_{n-2} \\
\overset{ibp}=&\ \frac1{n-1}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^{n-1} }+\frac{n-2}{n-1}I_{n-2}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

The substitution makes the integral  $$\int\cos^{n-1}(θ)\,dθ$$ if I am right and the absolute value is ignored. The reduction formula is $\cos^{n-2}θ\sinθ+(n-2)(\int \cos^{n-3}θ\,dθ-\int\cos^{n-1}\,dθ)$

This is after a bit of integration by parts of $\cos^{n-2}θ$ and $\cosθ$, pythagorean identity and basic integral properties. Also,remember that $x=\secθ$ just as @Tavish said.

This will not look like the textbook form, but using tan(arcsecθ)=xsin(arcsecθ)=x$\sqrt{1-\frac {1}{x^2}}$ and substitution of the change of variable got me dx= $x^2\sqrt{1-\frac {1}{x^2}}$dθ=secθtanθdθ.

Finally we get your original integral after some simplification is:
$x^{2-n}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}+(n-2)[\int \frac{x^{3-n}-x^{1-n}}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx]$= $\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{|x|x^{n-2}}+(n-2)[\int \frac{x^{3-n}}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx-\int\frac{x^{1-n}}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx]$

You can put it inti $I_{n-N}$ form if needed.

Correct me and give me feedback please!

Comment: Ok! Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer.  I solved it like @Quanto. But you answer was helpful!! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the *hyperbolic* substitution $\:x=\cosh t,\enspace  t\ge 0$, $\:\mathrm d x=\sinh t\,\mathrm d t$, so that the integral becomes, since $\:\cosh^2t-\sinh^2t=1$,
$$\int\frac{\sinh t\,\mathrm dt}{\sinh t\cosh^nt}=\int\frac{\mathrm dt}{\cosh^nt},$$
that we'll denote $I_n$.

Now, to obtain the recurrence relation, we'll use integration by parts for $I_n$: setting
\begin{cases}u=\dfrac 1{\cosh^{n-2}t}, &\quad\mathrm du=-\dfrac{(n-2)}{\cosh^{n-1}t}\sinh t\,\mathrm dt, \\[1ex]
\mathrm dv=\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\cosh^2t},&\quad v=\tanh t.
\end{cases}
we obtain
$$I_n=\frac{\tanh t}{\cosh^{n-2}t}+(n-2)\int\frac{\tanh t\,\mathrm dt}{\cosh^{n-1}t}=\frac{\sinh t}{\cosh^{n-1}t}+(n-2)\int\frac{\sinh^2 t\,\mathrm dt}{\cosh^{n}t}$$

Can you proceed?

Comment: I solved it. Thanks for taking your time to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

With $$I_n:=\int\frac{dx}{x^n\sqrt{x^2-1}},$$

$$I_{n-2}-I_{n}=\int\frac{x^2-1}{x^{n}\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx=\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^{n}}dx.$$

Then by parts, this is

$$-\frac1{n-1}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^{n-1}}+\frac1{n-1}I_{n-2}.$$

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.  Thanks again!!